# Times (or Termes) with protrusion/hanging in ConTeXt MkIV

Tags: fonts, context, microtype

On the ConTeXt wiki, http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Protrusion#MkIV, some examples are given of how to use Termes fonts and how to use microtypographical extensions.  The bottom example works, but

- I am unable to change fonts successfully
- I am only able to enable the microtypographical extensions by using the last example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I can say: is 'Works for me'. What version of ConTeXt are you using?

Comment: Mk IV, installed it from Debian with `apt-get install context`, I think it comes from TeX Live 2009._something_.  I am compiled the file using: `context [file]`.  All other things seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Your ConTeXt is probably too old to work properly, you will need a newer ConTeXt. The easiest way to get one is to install the standalone context installation, see the [ConTeXt minimals](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Minimals) page in the Contextgarden wiki for details. You can install that distribution without it interfering with anything else in your systems, and it is easy to keep it up-to-date with the recent developments.